# Merge multiple files based on regex

Tags: bash

How do I merge two files with matching characters/digits before an underscore using a for loop? I have many files in the directory

Input:

```
SRR9200887_1.fastq
SRR9200887_2.fastq
SRR9200888_1.fastq
SRR9200888_2.fastq
SRR9200889_1.fastq
SRR9200889_2.fastq
```

Expected output:

```
SRR9200887.fastq
SRR9200888.fastq
SRR9200889.fastq
```

My attempt:

```
for l in $(ls *.fastq | cut -d_ -f1 | sort |uniq); do cat ${l}*.fastq
```

Comment: The following page contains hints why it is not useful to use the output of `ls`: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for f in *_*.fastq; do cat "$f" >> "${f%_*}.fastq"; done
```

Comment: Your approach seems to me the most original and creative one. Its main disadvantage (compared to the other solution) is that it's not idempontent: You can't simply re-run the code on the same input data, because you need for your algorithm `>>`.

Answer (score 5):

With `bash` and its [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for i in *_1.fastq; do
  cat "${i%_*.fastq}_1.fastq" "${i%_*.fastq}_2.fastq" > "${i%_*.fastq}.fastq";
done
```

`${i%_*.fastq}` outputs `$i` without `_` and all following it, e.g. `SRR9200887`.

Answer (score 2):

To `cat` the files together, assuming you have matching "_1.fastq" and "_2.fastq" for every "SRR", one potential option is:

```
SRR_array=(*_1.fastq)
for f in "${SRR_array[@]%%_*}"
do
    cat "$f"_1.fastq "$f"_2.fastq > "$f".fastq
done
```

If you wanted to delete the _1.fastq and _2.fastq files after merging them together:

```
SRR_array=(*_1.fastq)
for f in "${SRR_array[@]%%_*}"
do
    cat "$f"_1.fastq "$f"_2.fastq > "$f".fastq
    rm "$f"_1.fastq "$f"_2.fastq
done
```

Answer (score 1):

One `bash` idea:

```
while read -r pfx
do
    cat "${pfx}"_*.fastq >> "${pfx}".fastq
done < <(find . -name "*_*.fastq" | cut -d'_' -f1 | sort -u)
```

---

Tweaking OP's current code:

```
for l in $(ls -1 *_*.fastq | cut -d_ -f1 | sort | uniq)
do
    cat ${l}_*.fastq >> "${l}".fastq
done
```

Where:

- we look for files with a `_` in the name; if the script is run more than once this will insure we don't pick up the previous concatenated files
- make sure `ls` lists one file per line (hence the `-1`)
- in this case `sort | uniq` could be replaced with `sort -u`

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk (untested):

```
awk '
    FNR==1 {
        out = FILENAME
        sub(/_[0-9]+/,"",out)
        if ( out != prev ) {
            close(prev)
            prev = out
        }
    }
    { print > out }
' *_*.fastq
```

That will concatenate files with the same suffix no matter how many files have the same suffix, not just 2.